# Описать правильно функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

Имеется такой код:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

interface IUser
{
    name: string;
}

interface IValue
{
    user: IUser;
    isAuth: boolean;
}

export interface IUserContext
{

}

export const UserCtx = createContext<IUserContext>({} as IUserContext);

function App()
{
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState<IUser>({} as IUser);
    const [ isAuth, setIsAuth ] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const setValue: <T extends keyof IValue>(key: T, value: IValue[ T ]) => void = (key, value) =>
    {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));

        switch (key)
        {
            case "user": {
                setUser(value);
                break;
            }
            case "isAuth": {
                setIsAuth(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    setValue("user", { name: "test" });

    const userContext: IUserContext =
    {
        user,
        isAuth,
        setValue
    };
}
```

Как мне правильно описать функцию `setValue`? На данный момент я получаю ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> (parameter) value: boolean | IUser
> Аргумент типа "boolean | IUser" нельзя назначить параметру типа "SetStateAction".
> Тип "IUser" не может быть назначен для типа "SetStateAction". ts(2345)

Answer (score 2):

Так это работать не будет. То, что вы хотите, лучше делать через хук [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Тем не менее, некоторые рабочие практики из типизации редюсеров можно применить к вашему варианту (к слову, это тоже плохая практика)

Удалил ненужный для примера код.

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
}

//ключи сеттеров 
enum keys {
  isAuth = "isAuth",
  user = "user"
}

//креатор объекта аутентификации
const createAuthValue = (authState: boolean) =>
  ({
    key: keys.isAuth,
    auth: authState,
  } as const);

//креатор объекта с юзером
const createUserValue = (user: IUser) =>
  ({
    key: keys.user,
    user: user,
  } as const);

//возможные значения, которые принимает setValue
type Value = ReturnType<typeof createAuthValue> | ReturnType<typeof createUserValue>

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({} as IUser);
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const setValue= (value: Value) => {
    switch (value.key) {
      case keys.user: {
        setUser(value.user);
        break;
      }
      case keys.isAuth: {
        setIsAuth(value.auth);
        break;
      }
    }
  };
  
  //вызываем общий сеттер и передаем туда креатор объекта с юзером 
  setValue(createUserValue({ name: "test" }));
}
```

В ответе на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1317908/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-actions-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/1318577#1318577) вопросе есть ссылки для более подробный инфы по типизации редюсера.